# Excel VBA Nested Loop Issue

Tags: vba, excel

really hoping someone can help me.

I'm new to VBA only started picking bits up a few weeks back. I'm trying to create a nested loop to consolidate data from multiple tabs in Excel.

This is based on the worksheet name beginning ">" and column 3 containing a True or False value. Data is then pasted into a sheet called import.

Both loops seem to work independently but I cant get them to work together.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub TestImport()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Criteria As Boolean
Dim C As Integer
Criteria = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Import").UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If Left(WS.Name, 1) = ">" Then
    For C = 2 To WS.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
    If WS.Cells(C, 3) = Criteria Then
        WS.Range(Cells(C, 5), Cells(C, 12)).Copy
        Worksheets("Import").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
        Next C
    End If
Next WS
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Import").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `I cant get them to work together.` - What _exactly_ isn't working?

Comment: Why not directly `WS.Cells(C, 5).Resize(1, 8).Copy`?

Comment: Thanks I will use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looping across the sheets in the workbook, you should fully qualify any ranges with which you are working. Specifically, the following line:

```
WS.Range(Cells(C, 5), Cells(C, 12)).Copy
```

should be changed to:

```
WS.Range(WS.Cells(C, 5), WS.Cells(C, 12)).Copy
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you